# Opening directions in Google maps directly

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, nativeapplication

I am using below code to open direction from current location to particular location in Google Maps.

But the code first shows me "Open With dialog" giving user choice to open with other components also. I want user to be taken directly to Google maps without giving him choice to select. How can I do that?

```
   String uri = "https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr="+location;
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
   startActivity(i);
```

Comment: And if the user does not have the Google Maps app...?

Comment: @MarkChorley I think all android phones have Google maps app by default?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below format (not officially supported):

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/My%20location/DESTINATION_ADDRESS
```

OR

```
https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=DESTINATION_ADDRESS
```

eg:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/My%20location/world%20of%20coca%20cola

https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=world%20of%20coca%20cola
```

Where DESTINATION_ADDRESS is the destination address you want to navigate to.